# Solving for Dimensions of Boxes

Tags: linear-algebra

A packing company supplies storage boxes in three different sizes: small, medium, and large.
All three types of box have the same ratio of width:length and height:length.

It is noted that:
A. Eight small boxes fit neatly inside one medium box.
B. The length of the small box is the same as the height of the medium box.
C. The base area (i.e. width times length) of a large box is 9 times smaller than the base area of the small box.
D. The lengths of all three boxes added together is 2.4 m.
E. The width of the medium box is twice the height of the small box.

What are the lengths of the three different boxes?

My attempt at a solution:
S,M,L Size of boxes , small medium large
L,W,H Dimenions of boxes, Length, Width Height,
Dimension is followed by the type of box (its size): S,M,L

A : 8(Ls *WS * HS) = LM *WM *HM

B: Ls= HM

C: LL * WL = 9 Ls WS

D: LS + LM + LL =2.4

E: WM = 2HS

I first thought, Need to get like terms for D, to find out the length of one of the boxes.
I noticed E and B can be subsituted into A to get

8(LS *WS * HS) = LM * WM * HM
8(LS *WS * HS) = LM * 2HS * LS

To get 2LM = 8WS

so LM = 4W S

But from here I am unsure how to go about solving to get all three sides. Are there any potential further steps that can be seen?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting math for this site.

Comment: at point C, "smaller" or "larger" ?

Comment: @GCab Must be "larger".  "Smaller" contradicts similarity of boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of hints.

All the boxes are similar.  The volumes of similar figures varies as the cube of corresponding sides.  Therefore, part A tells us that the dimensions of the medium box are twice those of the small box.

The corresponding faces of the boxes are similar, and the areas of similar figures varies as the square of corresponding sides.  Therefore part C (with "smaller" corrected to "larger") tells us that the dimension of the large box are three times those of the small box.

Now you should be able to eliminate all but three variables, and solve the problem.